# Spreadsheet セルにサムネイルを表示する方法

Tags: google-apps-script

下のコードを実行すると正常に終了しますが、サムネイルは表示されません。　何が問題なのでしょうか？

```
function dispThumbnail() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("a01.jpg").next();
   sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(file.getThumbnail());
   sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(file.getId());
 }
```

因みにGoogle Develpers リファランス Class File getThumbnail()には`Return type=Blob, Brief descriptionにはGets a thumbnail image for the file, or null if no thumbnail exists.とあります。

```
sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(file.getId());
```

は正しく表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

[`Range#setValue(value)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) の有効な引数は `numeric, string, boolean or date` と書かれていますから、 [`File#getThumbnail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getThumbnail()) の返すBlobを指定することはできません。

代わりに [`Spreadsheet#insertImage(blob, column, row)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertImage(Blob,Integer,Integer)) を使って、

```
function dispThumbnail() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("a01.jpg").next();
   sheet.insertImage(file.getThumbnail(), 1, 1);
   sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(file.getId());
}
```

このように書けるはずなのですが、現時点ではそもそも `getThumbnail()` がBlobを返してくれません。

[Issue 4344 - google-apps-script-issues - DriveApp file.getThumbnail() always returns null](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4344)

上のバグ報告によれば、とりあえず Drive Advanced Service の方を使ってくれということらしいです。

1. `リソース > Google の拡張サービス...` で Drive API を有効化
2. そのダイアログの下部にも書かれている `Google デベロッパーコンソール` から、Drive API を選択して、これも有効化。

その上で、例えばこんな感じに。

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("a01.png").next();
  sheet.insertImage(Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink, 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(file.getId());
}
```

`thumbnailLink` で得られたURLを [`=image()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) に指定してもいいですね。

Comment: お蔭で画像は表示できるようになりました。　関連して２つ質問させてください。
１．アドオンで配布した場合、ユーザも又Drive API 有効化をしなければならないのでしょうか？
２．thumbnailLink はそのまま =image() の中に埋め込んで使う構文がどうしても分かりません。　これも教えてください。

Comment: 1.REST APIをラップするような仕組みと考えると、開発者（スクリプトの所有者？）が有効化するだけでいい気はします、が確証はないです。 2.`=image()` がなんなのかわからないのであればドキュメント（https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333）を。スクリプト的にはただの数式なので `setValue()` が使えます。

Comment: まだ解決しませんので教えてください。　
sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("=image(Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink)"); と書きましたが　Cell(1,1)には#ERROR!　と表示され、「数式の解析エラーです。」メッセージが表示されます。　setFormula()を使用しても同様です。　文は間違っていないと思うのですが、何が問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、thumbnailLinkで取得した文字列（URL）を `=image("http://...")` という形になるように数式に埋め込んで使える、という意味合いでした。DriveAPIを数式内で使うことはできません。

Comment: ようやく分かりました。　有難うございます。